# How to get the correct return type of Object.keys(o)

Tags: typescript

```
const o1 = { f: () => 1 }
const keys1 = Object.keys(o1) // ['f']

class C { f() {} }
const c1 = new C()
const keys2 = Object.keys(c1) // []
```

The following `ObjectKeys` returns `['f']` for `class C`. This is my problem.

```
type ObjectKeys<T> = T extends object ? { [Key in keyof T]: Key }[keyof T] : never

function objectKeys<T>(o: T) {
  if (o === undefined || o === null) {
    return []
  }

  return (Object.keys(o) as any) as ReadonlyArray<ObjectKeys<T>>
}

const keys3 = objectKeys(o1) // Return type is ['f']
const keys4 = objectKeys(c1) // Return type is ['f'], but the value is []
```

I know TypeScript can never know if a property is hidden or not. But I would like to get rid of those class method names that we know are not visible for `Object.keys(o)`.

Comment: The prototype chain is not well represented in TypeScript's type system.  There are [closed](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/11558) issues [asking](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/20922) for better support but they have been declined.  I don't think there's any good answer here other than for you to manually keep track of which properties you care about.  Also this question seems to think that objects will *only* have the keys that the compiler knows about, but that is [not true](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/pull/12253#issuecomment-263132208).